# Kernel of ring homomorphisms and subring test

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Let $R$ be a ring and we adjoin an element "$a$" to the ring $R$ with some relation $f(a) = 0$. The resulting ring is $R[x]/\langle f\rangle= R'$ (say). Now latest consider the inclusion map $i$ from $R$ to $R[x]$ and then consider the canonical projection $\pi$ from $R[x]$ to $R'$. Clearly both the maps $i$, $\pi$ are homomorphisms, so their composition $\pi\circ i = g$ (say) is also a homomorphism.

Then I am very interested to see what is $\ker(g)$ but I couldn't find it. Help me.

Also it is written that of $g$ is not injective, then we can't identify $R$ with a subring of $R'$.

I couldn't understand why?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please use Mathjax to format the math formulas in your post. [Here is a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/742).

Comment: To see an example where the resulting map is not an embedding, consider $R=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, and $f(x) = 2x-1$. Then $2$ lies in the kernel, since $g(2) = \pi(2) = \pi(2 + 2(2x-1)) = \pi(4x) = \pi(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel is of course the intersection of the ideal $(f(x))$ of $R[x]$ with (the image of) $R$.

When $R$ is an integral domain, if $f(x)$ has degree at least 1 then this intersection consists only of $0$; indeed, the elements of $(f(x))$ are multiples of $f(x)$, and because $R$ is an integral domain, every nonzero multiple of $f(x)$ has degree greater than or equal to $1$. Thus, $R\cap(f(x))=\{0\}$. So the kernel of the composite map $R\to R[x]\to R[x]/(f(x))$ is trivial in that case.

But if $R$ is not an integral domain, then the ideal $(f(x))$ may contain nonzero constants.

For example, take $R=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, and suppose you try to adjoin a multiplicative inverse to $2$, which is nilpotent in this ring. That would mean "adjoining" an $a$ that satisfies $f(x) = 2x-1$.

Now, $2(2x-1)$ lies in the ideal $(2x-1)$ in $R[x]$. But $2(2x-1) = 2$ (since $(2)(2)=0$ and $-2=2$ in $R$). So $2$ lies in the kernel of the map.

So $\ker(g) = R\cap(f(x))$ in $R[x]$; under some circumstances you can prove that this is trivial: among them, if $R$ is an integral domain, or more generally if $\deg(f)\gt 0$ and the leading coefficient of $f$ is not a zero divisor (but this is not the full set of circumstances under which you could show that). But for more general rings, you can certainly have nontrivial kernel.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel of $g$ is $\{r\in\mathcal R\mid \pi(r)=0\}=\{r\in\mathcal R\mid r\in(f(x))\}$.
If, and only if,  this kernel is zero,  we then have an embedding of $\mathcal R$ into $\mathcal R'$ (in which case we can identify it with a subring of $\mathcal R'$).